# What Postgres packages are really needed?

Tags: postgresql

I have new Vultr Ubuntu 18.04 server on which I plan to install a Rails 5.2 app on Postgres and RVM.

Which Postgres packages are needed for a Rails app? I will use PG Admin to view the database as well.

- This [tutorial](https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/18.04) says to install postgresql-common + postgresql-9.5 + libpq-dev
- This [one](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/ruby-on-rails-ror-with-postgresql-on-ubuntu-16-04/) says postgresql + postgresql-contrib + libpq-dev
- This [one](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-install-postgresql-on-ubuntu-18-04/) says postgresql + postgresql-contrib

Which is the right one? Isn't postgresql-10 better than postgresql-9.5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you only need `postgresql-common` and `postgresql` on the server.

`posstgresql-dev` is needed if you are compiling clients

`pg_admin` is usually installed on your desktop, no the server.

version 10 is newer and considered stable by the developers, I'd pick it over 9.x